# String Encryption at compile time

Tags: c++, string, encryption

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
char *test = Encryption("Test");
```

and if someone is looking at the file after it was compiled the string "Test" should be encrypted. I'm not looking for something like this:

```
char *test = Decrypt("=7fg%ghhz");
```

or

```
char *test = Encrypt('T', 'e', 's', 't');
```

I want to be able to easily change strings and view them as they are in my project, but they should be encrypted after the executeable was compiled. Also I can't use C++11 (or above). I found a code snippet online, but since it's C++11 i can't use it.

```
template <int X> struct EnsureCompileTime {
        enum : int {
            Value = X
        };
    };

    //Use Compile-Time as seed
#define Seed ((__TIME__[7] - '0') * 1  + (__TIME__[6] - '0') * 10  + \
                  (__TIME__[4] - '0') * 60   + (__TIME__[3] - '0') * 600 + \
                  (__TIME__[1] - '0') * 3600 + (__TIME__[0] - '0') * 36000)

    constexpr int LinearCongruentGenerator(int Rounds) {
        return 1013904223 + 1664525 * ((Rounds> 0) ? LinearCongruentGenerator(Rounds - 1) : Seed & 0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
#define Random() EnsureCompileTime<LinearCongruentGenerator(10)>::Value //10 Rounds
#define RandomNumber(Min, Max) (Min + (Random() % (Max - Min + 1)))

    template <int... Pack> struct IndexList {};

    template <typename IndexList, int Right> struct Append;
    template <int... Left, int Right> struct Append<IndexList<Left...>, Right> {
        typedef IndexList<Left..., Right> Result;
    };

    template <int N> struct ConstructIndexList {
        typedef typename Append<typename ConstructIndexList<N - 1>::Result, N - 1>::Result Result;
    };
    template <> struct ConstructIndexList<0> {
        typedef IndexList<> Result;
    };

    const char XORKEY = static_cast<char>(RandomNumber(0, 0xFF));
    constexpr char EncryptCharacter(const char Character, int Index) {
        return Character ^ (XORKEY + Index);
    }

    template <typename IndexList> class CXorString;
    template <int... Index> class CXorString<IndexList<Index...> > {
    private:
        char Value[sizeof...(Index)+1];
    public:
        constexpr CXorString(const char* const String)
            : Value{ EncryptCharacter(String[Index], Index)... } {}

        char* decrypt() {
            for (int t = 0; t < sizeof...(Index); t++) {
                Value[t] = Value[t] ^ (XORKEY + t);
            }
            Value[sizeof...(Index)] = '\0';
            return Value;
        }

        char* get() {
            return Value;
        }
    };
#define XorS(X, String) CXorString<ConstructIndexList<sizeof(String)-1>::Result> X(String)
#define XorString( String ) ( CXorString<ConstructIndexList<sizeof( String ) - 1>::Result>( String ).decrypt() )
```

I can only use native C++. If it's possible and you know how it's done, please let me know, i've been searching for a solution quite a while now!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  _"I want to"_ is not a question.

Comment: No C++11 = no compile-time computation other than the preprocessor.

Comment: @RichardCritten I tried everything i mentioned above. I tried xoring it, but since i stored the string before xoring it it ended up showing in ida. I also tried encrypting it with aes outside of the program and then decrypting the encrypted string on use. But these weren't what i was looking for. And since i have no clue on how to do it without C++11 when the executeable is compiled i came here to ask if any of you knows how it could be done and share his experiences...

Comment: @RustyX My project is a Xbox360 executeable. The xbox360 sdk only lets me create the project in vs2010, but later i can edit and compile the project in vs2017. Is it possible to somehow "upgrade" to c++11?

Comment: I suppose you could write a code pre-processor that deals with `Encrypted("...");` strings before sending it to the compiler. But maybe it would be better to read in the program's strings in at startup and decrypt them then?

Comment: @Galik as i stated i dont want to do stuff like this: char *text = Decrypt("encryptedtexthere");, the preprocessor approach seems interesting, i'm going to try to find anything on it thanks!